# How to capitalize only the title of each string in the list?

Tags: python, text, format

WHOLE QUESTION: Write a function that takes as a parameter a list of strings and returns a list containing the each string capitalized as a title. That is, if the input parameter is `["apple pie", "brownies","chocolate","dulce de leche","eclairs"]`, your function should return `["Apple Pie", "Brownies","Chocolate","Dulce De Leche","Eclairs"]`.

My program(UPDATED):

I THINK I GOT MY PROGRAM RUNNING NOW! The problem is when I enter: `["apple pie"]` it is returning: `['"Apple Pie"']`

```
def Strings():
  s = []
  strings = input("Please enter a list of strings: ").title()
  List = strings.replace('"','').replace('[','').replace(']','').split(",")
  List = List + s

  return List

def Capitalize(parameter):
  r = []
  for i in parameter:
    r.append(i)

  return r

def main():
  y = Strings()
  x = Capitalize(y)
  print(x)

main()
```

I am getting an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'`
Please help!

Comment: You've given us a description of the problem you're trying to solve, so, what's your question?

Comment: How do I capitalize the title of each string in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the name list and then for each name, change the case of first letter only by specifying the index number of first letter. And then add the returned result with the remaining chars then finally append the new name to the already created empty list.

```
def Strings():

  strings = input("Please enter a list of strings: ")
  List = strings.replace('"','').replace('[','').replace(']','').split(",")


  return List

def Capitalize(parameter):
  r = []
  for i in parameter:
    m = ""
    for j in i.split():
      m += j[0].upper() + j[1:] + " "
    r.append(m.rstrip())  


  return r

def main():
  y = Strings()
  x = Capitalize(y)
  print(x)

main()
```

**OR**

```
import re
strings = input("Please enter a list of strings: ")
List = [re.sub(r'^[A-Za-z]|(?<=\s)[A-Za-z]', lambda m: m.group().upper(), name) for name in strings.replace('"','').replace('[','').replace(']','').split(",")]
print(List)
```

Comment: It is working but I want the strings to be printed out with quotation marks as referred in the question

Comment: You program: `["apple pie"]` returning
`['Apple pie']`

Comment: You program: `["apple pie"]` returning
`['Apple pie']`

Comment: Still I am getting the same thing

Comment: ['Apple Pie']                    @Avinash Raj

Comment: Did you fix it?       @Avinash Raj

Answer (score 0):

You're operating on the list, not a element of the list.

```
 r.title()
```

This makes no sense.

Comment: fix that!                   @bald

Comment: I want the strings to printed out with quotation marks