# How to capitalize the title of each string in a list?

Tags: python, format

Question: Write a function that takes as a parameter a list of strings and returns a list containing the each string capitalized as a title. That is, if the input parameter is `["apple pie","brownies","dulce de leche"]`, your function should return `["Apple Pie","Brownies","Dulce De Leche"]`.

I wrote this program. The problem is if I enter `["apple pie", "brownies","dulce de leche"]`, it is returning `['Apple Pie', ' Brownies', 'Dulce De Leche']`
As the question suggests, each string has to be printed out with quotes and no space after commas.
PLEASE HELP!

Here is my program:

```
def Strings():
  s = []
  strings = input("Please enter a list of strings: ").title()
  List = strings.replace('"',"").replace('[','').replace(']','').split(",")
  List = List + s

  return List

def Capitalize(parameter):
  r = []
  for i in parameter:
    r.append(i)

  return r

def main():
  y = Strings()
  x = Capitalize(y)
  print(x)

main()
```

Comment: this is a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463718/how-to-capitalize-only-the-title-of-each-string-in-the-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like my previous answer, you just need to join the list with `","` and you need to add `["` , `"]` at the start and at the end.

```
def Strings():

  strings = input("Please enter a list of strings: ")
  List = strings.replace('"','').replace('[','').replace(']','').split(",")


  return List

def Capitalize(parameter):
  r = []
  for i in parameter:
    m = ""
    for j in i.split():
      m += j[0].upper() + j[1:] + " "
    r.append(m.rstrip())  


  return '["' + '","'.join(r)+ '"]'

def main():
  y = Strings()
  x = Capitalize(y)
  print(x)

main()
```

Comment: you just answered the duplicate of this question.  this is a copy and paste of that answer . . .

Comment: that's not how stack overflow works!

Comment: @dbliss you see in the previous question, i can't able to understand his needs. But this clearly explain what actually his needs are. I don't want the rep anymore, if the op delete this question, i'm ready to add this to my previous answer. But i saw many contiguous questions like this before. question2 , a continuation of question 1.

Comment: the questions are from two students who have posted to SO in a desperate attempt to get someone to do their homework for them.  neither question shows any research effort.  at the least, these questions should be combined.  it's possible they should be removed altogether.

Comment: i agree with combined but i don't agree with removed altogether because op somewhat shows his attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why anyone would want to do this, but here you go:

```
s = "["
for i in x:
    s += '"' + i + '",'
print s + "]"
```

Comment: why it is printing `None` after each execution?

Comment: Where did you put it in your code? Avinash's answer is better anyway.

Comment: `None`                                              ...................

Comment: In the function `Capitalize()`

Comment: No, just replace ```print(x)``` with my code. Keep everything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Capitalize(parameter):
    return ["\""+i.strip().strip("\"").title()+"\"" for i in s[1:-1].split(",")]

title = Capitalize(y)
print "[" + ",".join(title) + "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is being entered as a legitimate python list [...] then you can use the json module to turn this string in a python object (namely a list) and then back again after you title the strings, `json.dumps()` gives you control over the separators, e.g.:

```
>>> from json import loads, dumps
>>> strings = loads(input("Please enter a list of strings: "))
>>> print(dumps([s.title() for s in strings], separators=(',',':')))
["Apple Pie","Brownies","Dulce De Leche"]
```